# Sorting and filtering a big ObservableCollection without blocking the UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await

I have a list (only around 100 items) and I need to apply sorting and filtering on it, but the problem is that the UI gets blocked for like a second, and if there is any animation it gets skipped. I know that I have to use other threads to avoid UI blocking and get back to the main thread to update the UI. But in my case, I only have to filter or sort the displayed list, so I can only do it on the main thread.

there is only two ways,
either clear the list and start adding filtred and sorted items to it :

```
MyList.Clear();
foreach(var item in SortedAndFiltredList)
{
  MyList.Add(item);
}
```

Or reinstanciate the list :

```
MyList = new ObservableCollection(SortedAndFiltredList);
```

this two options both gets the UI to hand for like a second and it's really not pleasant. I kept searching for a way but I couldn't find any solution. Is there is any experts who can tell me whats the appropriate way to acheive this ?

Thank you so much

Comment: Take a look on https://github.com/mattleibow/RangedObservableCollection , in general just ReplaceRange of items, it will allow to update you list in one UI call which should not give such huge UI lag as you have. As for now you have 1 update on Clear and update on each iteration of your foreach. Using ReplaceRange (with already ordered list) all this will be done in 1 OnCollectionChange event

Comment: @choper thanks ! I have a question tho, is using a `List`  instead of `ObservableCollection`   is a better idea ? with `MyList = new List(SortedAndFiltredList);`

Comment: Dependent on what you want to have in the end, if those manipulations that you provided as example is the only one, then yes, mostly it will be more easy to use it. If you have another logic with `Add` or `Remove` some separate raw with UI updates of this actions then `ObservableCollection` is much better for such purpose.

Comment: @choper there is only filtering and sorting, but even using a list didn't really make a big difference ... I don't get it really.

Comment: The specific for the ObservableCollection is that it would notify the listener whenever an item has been added or removed from the list. It would show in UI of Xamarin.